# shift not working in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

**yshift is not working with points defined by 'tkz-euclide'**

**How to make it work?**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)

\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B) 

%not working
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw [|<->|] (A) -- node[above]{2 cm} (B);
\end{scope}

%working
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw [|<->|] (0,0) -- node[above]{2 cm} (2,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you really need the shift inside the scope, you have to write `\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-1cm}]` instead of `\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]`. But you should be careful when using `transform canvas` key. Also, it is necessary to adjust the bounding box that is calculated incorrectly in such case.

Answer (score 2):

**Now i got a solution....**

> \draw [|<->|,>=stealth] ([yshift=1cm]A) -- node[above]{2 cm} ([yshift=1cm]B);

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)

\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B) 

%now working
\draw [|<->|,>=stealth] ([yshift=1cm]A) -- node[above]{2 cm} ([yshift=1cm]B);


%working
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw [|<->|] (0,0) -- node[above]{2 cm} (2,0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with tkz-euclide

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)

\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B) 
\tkzDrawSegment[|<->|]([yshift=-1cm]A,[yshift=-1cm]B)
\tkzLabelSegment[above]([yshift=-1cm]A,[yshift=-1cm]B){$2$ cm}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]